# How to streamline mssql query that includes calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables containing data that I am attempting to get counts and then do calculations. I have a working query but it repetitious.

```
SELECT person_id,
(SELECT COUNT(*) from place_to_go where people.person_id=person_id) as 'Num_To_Go',
(SELECT COUNT(*) from place_been where people.person_id=person_id) as 'Num_Visited',
((​SELECT​ COUNT(*)​ ​FROM​ place_been ​WHERE​ people.person_id=person_id)​ /​ (​SELECT COUNT(*) ​FROM​ place_to_go ​WHERE​ people.person_id=person_id))​ ​*​ 100 ​AS​ ​'Perc_Visited'
FROM people;
```

What I'm trying accomplish is to not have the repeated sub queries for the percentage calculation. Any changes I make to that end in syntax errors and it's getting quite frustrating.

Thought I may have been able to use

```
SELECT person_id,
(SELECT COUNT(*) from place_to_go where people.person_id=person_id) as 'Num_To_Go',
(SELECT COUNT(*) from place_been where people.person_id=person_id) as 'Num_Visited',
(CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,0), 'Num_To_Go'))/(CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,0), 'Num_Visited')​) ​*​ 100 ​AS​ ​'Perc_Visited'
FROM people;
```

But that ends in an error converting data type varchar to numeric

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Left join to subqueries, with the count and group by taking place in the subquery... answer coming up..

Answer (score 2):

I would use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT person_id, Num_To_Go, Num_Visited, (Num_To_Go * 1.0 / Num_Visited) * 100 AS Perc_Visited
FROM people p OUTER APPLY
     ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS Num_To_Go
       FROM place_to_go pg
       WHERE P.person_id = pg.person_id
     ) pg OUTER APPLY
     ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS Num_Visited
       FROM place_been pb
       WHERE p.person_id = pb.person_id
     ) pb;
```

Comment: Careful of that integer math. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using subquery

```
select *, (CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,0), Num_To_Go))/(CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,0), Num_Visited)​) ​*​ 100.00 ​AS​ ​'Perc_Visited'
from
(
SELECT person_id,
(SELECT COUNT(*) from place_to_go where people.person_id=person_id) as 'Num_To_Go',
(SELECT COUNT(*) from place_been where people.person_id=person_id) as 'Num_Visited',
FROM people
)A
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a stab in the dark, however, perhaps:

```
SELECT p.person_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT p2g.{id_column}) AS NumToGo,
       COUNT(DISTINCT pb.{id_column}) AS NNumVisited,
       ((COUNT(DISTINCT pb.{id_column}) * 1.0) / COUNT(DISTINCT p2g.{id_column})) * 100 AS Perc_Visited --* 1.0 due to integer math. I.e. 99/100 = 0
FROM people p
     LEFT JOIN place_to_go p2g ON p.person_id = p2g.person_id
     LEFT JOIN place_been pb ON p.person_id = pb.person_id
GROUP BY person_id;
```

Comment: Did you want to indicate to OP that {id_column} requires some additional work  from OP to get a runnable querty?

Comment: @SMor we both know I did not apart from by encapsulating the column names in braces (`{}`), rather brackets (`[]`). :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd tackle it: [Runnable Example](https://rextester.com/QHMO37929)

```
select ppl.person_id
, coalesce(ptg.cnt,0) as 'Num_To_Go'
, coalesce(pb.cnt,0) as 'Num_Visited'
, case 
    when coalesce(ptg.cnt,0) = 0 then 100 --avoid /0 error ; if there are no places to go let's say we've been to them all
    else 100.0 * coalesce(pb.cnt,0) / ptg.cnt
end 'Perc_Visited'
from people ppl
left outer join (select person_id, count(1) cnt from place_to_go group by person_id) ptg on ptg.person_id = ppl.person_id
left outer join (select person_id, count(1) cnt from place_been group by person_id) pb on pb.person_id = ppl.person_id
```

- I've moved the queries to get counts into subqueries under the FROM clause; so you get a count per person once for each of the tables (place_to_go, place_been), then reuse those results any time you require them.
- I join those subqueries using the person_id field.  I've used `left outer join`s so that even if a person doesn't have any records in either table, we still see that person in the results.
- I use `coalesce(cnt,0)` to ensure that should there be no records associated with a person we see `0` instead of `null`.
- I stuck a `case` statement around the logic to calculate a percentage, since division is involved and potentially the divisor may be 0, resulting in a divide-by-zero error.  This case statement ensures that in such situations we return 100%; and only use the calculation where we're safe from this exception.
- Finally, I stuck `100.0 *` in instead of `100 *` to ensure our solution can return non-integer results; i.e. so we're not truncated to 0 decimal places.

---

However, there's also an issue with your design.  It assumes that every place you've been to is listed in the places to go table.  If that assumption's true, you're better off having one table for `places_to_go` with a field to flag whether or not you've been.  That way you enforce that rule in your code, improve performance, and reduce space.

i.e. [Runnable Example](https://rextester.com/QAG68408)

```
create table places_to_go
(
    place_id bigint not null foreign key references places(place_id)
    , person_id bigint not null foreign key references people(person_id)
    , have_been bit not null default (0)
    --& indexes / primary key field for this table / whatever else as required
)

select ppl.person_id
, coalesce(ptg.cnt_to_go,0) as 'Num_To_Go'
, coalesce(ptg.cnt_have_been,0) as 'Num_Visited'
, case 
    when coalesce(ptg.cnt_to_go,0) = 0 then null --avoid /0 error ; 
    else 100.0 * ptg.cnt_have_been / ptg.cnt_to_go
end 'Perc_Visited'
from people ppl
left outer join 
(
    select person_id
    , count(1) cnt_to_go
    , count(case when have_been = 1 then 1 end) cnt_have_been
    from place_to_go
    group by person_id
) ptg 
on ptg.person_id = ppl.person_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your query up in a derived table. Do the final calculation on its result:

```
select person_id, [Num_To_Go], [Num_Visited],
       [Num_To_Go] * 100.0 / [Num_Visited]​ ​AS​ ​[Perc_Visited]
from
(
    SELECT person_id,
           (SELECT COUNT(*) from place_to_go where people.person_id=person_id) as [Num_To_Go],
           (SELECT COUNT(*) from place_been where people.person_id=person_id) as [Num_Visited]
    FROM people
) dt
```

Or have a CTE (common table expression):

```
with cte as
(
    SELECT person_id,
           (SELECT COUNT(*) from place_to_go where people.person_id=person_id) as [Num_To_Go],
           (SELECT COUNT(*) from place_been where people.person_id=person_id) as [Num_Visited]
    FROM people
)
select person_id, [Num_To_Go], [Num_Visited],
       [Num_To_Go] * 100.0 [Num_Visited] ​AS​ [Perc_Visited]
from cte
```

Comment: I do like that idea of a derived table. I've not had a need to use that before. As the database is small, not data centre scale, it should be better performance than what I had. Not having to traverse the tables multiple times and all.

Comment: Unfortunately this code suffers from the same error. You (and OP) are attempting to cast the string literal 'Num_To_Go' to decimal - something that no one bothered to explain to OP. This is the source of the original error. You are also selecting the same literal as a column (with no name / alias) in the final resultset - which isn't useful.

Comment: @SMor, 1) The question was how to streamline - not how to calculate. 2) Isn't that _literal as column_ some SQL Server specific thing? Anyway, I'll fix that now, stay tuned!